# How to use Google Places Autocomplete API in React Native Android?

Tags: google-places-api, react-native

I am trying to use the Google Places Autocomplete API in RN Android (link to Google Doc as below). However, as the JS version of the API is meant for web app, I am not sure how to include the script into my RN Android code (original code for web application: ). Is there a way to use this API in RN? Or because the Google Places API also has an Android native version, do we have to write an Android native module and hook it to RN as explained in the "Guides(Android)/Native Modules" in the official RN doc?

Thanks a lot!

Google Places Autocomplete API JS: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete

Official RN doc on Native Modules: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Comment: This may help someone - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917439/google-places-api-reactnative/61567444#61567444

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use `npm install googleplaces` to install google places npm packages in your project and 
use `require('googleplaces')` in your code to access it

Checkout https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleplaces for more details. I've not tested it but I guess you can use it like other npm packages for react-native

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will test it myself.

Comment: @ZJL Hey, have you tested it. I am stuck at implementing this along with airbnb's react-native maps

Comment: @KiranMathewMohan I used the module FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete later for this feature

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete, as this will use Google Places API, which will not support mobile application API key restriction.

Comment: It seems to be a suggestion and does not look like and answer.

Comment: Sorry mean to point to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55917439/google-places-api-reactnative/61567444#61567444

Comment: I see. You need to earn enough reputation to add comments.